# Netbeans is not getting installed in my Mac,

Tags: java, macos, netbeans-8

I am trying to install Netbeans-12.0 on my mac. and it's showing that error:
[image: Java Error]

Here are mt java version details:

```
>>java -version
java version "1.8.0_271"
>>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_271
>>echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I have also tried with java version 15

Please help me to find the issue.

Comment: Unclear how you're installing Java, but it shouldn't be under `Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

Comment: I have installed the java using the installer file from Java official site.

Comment: Try using AdoptOpenJDK